# Powershell not passing Parameter to If Statement

Tags: powershell

I have this

```
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateSet('Yes','No')]
    [string]$ContinueSetup,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [Validateset('yes', 'no')]
    [string]$InstallDropbox = 'Yes',
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [Validateset('yes', 'no')]
    [string]$InstallSlack,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [Validateset('yes', 'no')]
    [string]$InstallOffice    
    )

if ($ContinueSetup -eq 'yes'){
    if ($InstallDropbox = 'yes'){
         write-host 'install dropbox'
             }
                else
                {write-host 'dropbox not selected'}    
    if ($InstallSlack = 'yes'){
        write-host 'install slack'
            }
                else
                {write-host 'slack not selected'}
    if ($InstallOffice = 'yes'){
        write-host 'install office'
            }
                else
                {write-host 'Office not selected'}
}
if ($continuesetup -eq 'no') {write-host 'no setup'; break}
```

It asks for my parameters as I want, but doesn't pass the parameters on, instead it just sets them all to 'yes'. Are parameters inherent? How should I set this so that it stops at each if statements, checks the parameter and does one of two actions, yes/no, and then moves onto the next if statement?

Comment: Please add your input, output and exptected output. I didn't get it.

Comment: Output: `PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> F:\blah blah blah.ps1
cmdlet blah blah blah.ps1 at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
ContinueSetup: yes
InstallDropbox: no
InstallSlack: yes
InstallOffice: no
install dropbox
install slack
install office`

Expected output: 
`PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> F:\blah blah blah.ps1
cmdlet blah blah blah.ps1 at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
ContinueSetup: yes
InstallDropbox: no
InstallSlack: yes
InstallOffice: no
Dropbox not selected
installslack
Office not selected`

Comment: Comparison in powershell is done using `-eq`, not `=`. Don't make parameters `yes` and `no`. There is already a built-in type that's immune to typos: `bool`. `$true` and `$false` are what you're after.

Comment: Wow DUH! Thanks a ton Daniel, I'll switch over to $true $false and replace = with -eq. Did it in the first one, just forgot it on the others :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparison in PowerShell is done using `-eq`, not `=`.

Also, do not make parameters `yes` and `no`. There is already a built-in type that's immune to typos: `bool`. `$true` and `$false` are what you're after

Comment: question on this, do a set the validateset to [Validateset(bool)] or do I leave it blank to select bool?

Comment: You don't need `ValidateSet` at all. There are only two possible values.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the bool type is designed for this sort of thing. Since they're only true or false, you don't have to include equality statements, which makes the code much more readable. Instead of

```
if( $InstallSlack -eq 'yes' )  # Note the -eq comparison is used in Powershell, not '=' or '=='
```

with a bool, you can just write

```
if( $InstallSlack )
```

which I think is much clearer.

To do the opposite, you put a `-not` in front of the bool:

```
if( -not $InstallSlack )
```

Here's your code rewritten with bool's (and with me changing the formatting a bit by adding some whitespace and aligning the code block indentation).

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [bool]$ContinueSetup,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [bool]$InstallDropbox = 'Yes',

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [bool]$InstallSlack,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [bool]$InstallOffice    
)

if ($ContinueSetup){
    if ($InstallDropbox){
         write-host 'install dropbox'
    }
    else{
        write-host 'dropbox not selected'
    }  

    if ($InstallSlack){
        write-host 'install slack'
    }
    else {
        write-host 'slack not selected'
    }

    if ($InstallOffice){
        write-host 'install office'
    }
    else {
        write-host 'Office not selected'
    }
}
else{
    write-host 'no setup'
    break
}
```

Bools are a very powerful programming concept. In Powershell, they can be combined/modified with `-not`, `-or`, `-and`, and a few others. [This link has the details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_logical_operators?view=powershell-5.1).

(Just for completeness, I'll note that some people (including me) don't like seeing [bool] parameters in Powershell. There's something called a [switch] parameter that can be used instead, but I wouldn't worry about it too much. [Here's a link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-5.1#switch-parameters).)

Answer (score 1):

I'd also recommend using `[switch]` instead of `[bool]` for your parameter types and not specifying `$true` as the default.  `SwitchParameter` parameters make invocation simplier and more straightforward.

```
Param (
    [switch]$Setup,
    [switch]$NoDropboxInstall,
    [switch]$NoSlackInstall,
    [switch]$NoOfficeInstall
)

if ($Setup) {
    "NoDropboxInstall: $NoDropboxInstall"
    "NoSlackInstall: $NoSlackInstall"
    "NoOfficeInstall: $NoOfficeInstall"
}
if (!$Setup) { 
    write-host 'no setup'
    return
}
```

Invoking the script is simpler:

```
.\parameters.ps1 -Setup -NoDropboxInstall
```

Output:

```
NoDropboxInstall: True
NoSlackInstall: False
NoOfficeInstall: False
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, an assignment statement can be an expression.  Occasionally useful, but confusing.  Any non-null result will be true.

```
if ($a = 'yes') {'yes'}
yes

if ($a = 'no') {'yes'} 
yes

if ($a = '') {'yes'}  
# nothing
```